# How to get value of oid type OctetString

Tags: c#, net-snmp, sharp-snmp

I am trying to get OID value (in string format) from Snmp device by using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging. it is displaying correctly for normal OID values, but while converting for Mac address containing('-') it does not converts properly and displays "\u0000 k???" any conversion recommendations, here is the code attached.

```
IList<Variable> result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V1,
                         new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sIpAddress), 
                         objSNMPv1Setting.Port),
                         new OctetString(objSNMPv1Setting.CommunityName), 
                         lstOid.Select(x => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(x))).ToList(),
                         objSNMPv1Setting.Timeout);

foreach (var o in result)
{            
    dictResponce.Add(o.Id.ToString(), o.Data.ToString());         
}
```

OID Value : ABC

```
o.Data.ToString() = ABC
```

OID Value ：00-20-6B-93-EC-81

```
o.Data.ToString() = \u0000 k???
```

Expected

OID Value ：00-20-6B-93-EC-81

```
o.Data.ToString() = 00-20-6B-93-EC-81
```

Comment: Strings that start with "\u0000" are empty strings.  Looks like that library does not expect failure, probably just not tested well enough.  Just file a bug report with the author.

Comment: It is by design. Decoding the actual type of an object requires the MIB documents, and that's only covered by #SNMP Pro, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmppro-samples/blob/release_2.0/Tests.NUnit/Mib/Tests/ObjectRegistryTestFixture.cs#L363 as the test case reveals, with MIB documents parsed, the decoder can format the information correctly.